# Pandas: Collapse rows in a Multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Below is my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2],
                         'B': [2, 2, 2, 3],
                         'C': [3, 3, 3, 4],
                         'D': ['Cancer A', 'Cancer B', 'Cancer A', 'Cancer B'],
                         'E': ['Ecog 9', 'Ecog 1', 'Ecog 0', 'Ecog 1'],
                         'F': ['val 6', 'val 1', 'val 0', 'val 1'],
                         'measure_m': [100, 200, 500, 300]})

print(df)

   A  B  C         D       E      F  measure_m
0  1  2  3  Cancer A  Ecog 9  val 6        100
1  1  2  3  Cancer B  Ecog 1  val 1        200
2  1  2  3  Cancer A  Ecog 0  val 0        500
3  2  3  4  Cancer B  Ecog 1  val 1        300
```

When I `pivot` this df without passing the index, I get this:

```
In [1280]: df.pivot(index=None, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
Out[1280]: 
  measure_m                           
A         1                          2
B         2                          3
C         3                          4
D  Cancer A Cancer B Cancer A Cancer B
E    Ecog 9   Ecog 1   Ecog 0   Ecog 1
F     val 6    val 1    val 0    val 1
0     100.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
1       NaN    200.0      NaN      NaN
2       NaN      NaN    500.0      NaN
3       NaN      NaN      NaN    300.0
```

I want instead of `4 rows` just `1` single row with all values of `measure_m` column, like below:

```
  measure_m                           
A         1                          2
B         2                          3
C         3                          4
D  Cancer A Cancer B Cancer A Cancer B
E    Ecog 9   Ecog 1   Ecog 0   Ecog 1
F     val 6    val 1    val 0    val 1
0     100.0    200.0    500.0    300.0
```

How to go about this?

Comment: whats the intention of this format? do you need it for a model or for presentation? just curious

Comment: Yes, I need to send this to UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df.set_index(list(df.columns[:-1])).T
```

Output:

```
A                1                          2
B                2                          3
C                3                          4
D         Cancer A Cancer B Cancer A Cancer B
E           Ecog 9   Ecog 1   Ecog 0   Ecog 1
F            val 6    val 1    val 0    val 1
measure_m      100      200      500      300
```

---

**Update** a little modification to match your output:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

(df.set_index(cols)
   [['measure_m']] # only need this if you have more columns
   .unstack(level=cols)
   .to_frame().T
)
```

Output:

```
  measure_m                           
A         1                          2
B         2                          3
C         3                          4
D  Cancer A Cancer B Cancer A Cancer B
E    Ecog 9   Ecog 1   Ecog 0   Ecog 1
F     val 6    val 1    val 0    val 1
0       100      200      500      300
```

Comment: The only thing here is that, `T` is a bit costly when it comes to huge data frames. Is there any thing else that can be done?

Comment: `T` is not that expensive, aside from copy your data. For example, it's much less costly than `pivot`, `unstack`, or even `set_index`. You can remove `T` if you don't really need the horizontal format. Other than that, I'm not sure there's a better approach.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thankyou.

Comment: Your second solution is failing, error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 elements`.

Comment: Your 2nd solution is failing. Can you please look at that?

Comment: @MayankPorwal double square bracket at second row. See updates.

Comment: Not sure why, it currently works with the sample data and `cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`.